# Why are my questions closed by these users?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I get blocked because my questions have been closed several times without a clear reason for closing them. Why were my questions closed?

---

[First question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629846/view-mysql-table-in-a-different-way-excel-vba) (*now closed and deleted*)

[Second question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657654/issue-getting-mysql-table-display-one-row-of-each-product-id-in-vba) (*now closed and deleted*)

[Third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660366/mysql-break-down-the-rows-to-columns) (*now deleted*)

Comment: Do you mean [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657654/issue-getting-mysql-table-display-one-row-of-each-product-id-in-vba) is on hold (which it is) or that you are blocked from asking more questions

Comment: Please, take some time to read the [help]. It will clarify the *on-hold* process and help improve your questions, so you'll receive answers and upvotes (instead of downvotes and question closure).

Comment: [Your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629846) had *Excel* and *VBA* in the title and in the tags. Were you trying to get the data in that format in MySQL? In Excel? Did you need help with VBA? It was **unclear**, and since you didn't give any example of a query or an Excel formula or anything else, I voted to close the question. Your second question was basically the same, but with a bunch of (imho) irrelevant info added. I still didn't know what you were trying to do. Perhaps I should have left a comment to explain what exactly was wrong with your question.

Comment: I see closing and voting on questions as ways to make sure stackoverflow is a collection of questions with good answers. When I ran into your first (now deleted) question it didn't include enough or was clear enough to be answered. Your second question (btw: you should have updated/edited your first question, but that is a different topic) is improved a little bit but still has issues as pointed out by Richard. So I felt a vote to put your question on hold again appropiate.  With regard to the comment you left on your question: I'm not easily offended, others might be.

Comment: The third question is a copy-paste repost of the first. That's not good.

Comment: A question following this one should be why do we allow that... 3 questions , 2 closed, 3rd gets answered... so 10 people have wasted their 10 votes and time to do moderation but in the end the poor OP gets his answer anyway..

Answer (score 10):

## Ask a question

In your now [on hold question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657654/issue-getting-mysql-table-display-one-row-of-each-product-id-in-vba) you never seem to actually ask a question.

After a bit of reading I figured out the implicit question; that you wanted the data to output as per the last table, but it was coming out like the one to last table. Describing what you're doing is useful, but it's easier to understand if you also ask an explicit question.

## Make your question as simple as possible

You seem to have a lot of extraneous information, 4 tables of data, each with many columns, provided as images. I'm sure that’s the real situation you're dealing with but is it really necessary for the question? Try to reduce it down to the bare minimum that replicates the problem; then the question will be far clearer.

## Your simpler version

You created a simpler version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660366/mysql-break-down-the-rows-to-columns#22660366) (ideally edit the existing question rather than reposting a new version), this suffers from the opposite problem; it isn't clear what you're stuggling with without seeing an attempt. Ideally try to find some middle ground between the two, the simplicity of this version with the attempted solution of the more complicated version.

It would be better to have really simple source data (2 tables, 2-3 columns each), the sql you use to try to get the output. An example of the output, and whats wrong with that output.

However, while not ideal this version is at least *clearer* and seems to be attracting answers

Comment: And it's clear to see that this user didn't read [any](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [the](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) topics in the help center on how to ask a question

Comment: Richard Tingle, thank you so much for your reply, the problem is that yesterday I asked this same question in a simple way, where I provided my code and example of the current output and the output i would want, but this crew blocked me, telling me that I am not making any effort to solve the issue. I am not a professional in programming sql, that is why i need help. Lots of people provide similar questions and they get answers, but when this crew comes in they just block anyone and vote negative on people. This is the place for people to seek help.

Comment: @user3458635 I can't see the now deleted version so can't comment specifically. However, the best questions simplify the problem and show your attempt to solve that simplified problem and how it didn't work

Comment: At the end of the question I gave an example without any image where the output is not what i want and i made an example of the output I would like. Also I said that I used pivot but still didn't get the desired results. I also stated that I might be wrong somewhere and would want some help. Isn't it fair enough?

Comment: Yes I deleted it today in the morning

Comment: @user3458635 As I say, without seeing the specific question it would be pure speculation on my part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660366/mysql-break-down-the-rows-to-columns

Comment: @user3458635 I've edited my answer, but basically thats too far the other way. Better to have really simple source data (2 tables, 3 columns each), the sql you use to try to get the output. An example of the output, and whats wrong with that output

Comment: the example of the output is what I wrote first and what i want to achieve is what i wrote in the second example. The problem is, I can't have it done the other way, because these tables are from Opencart. We have an online store, where we want to manipulate data. But it is not comfortable to edit data with product_id repeated 3 times. We have over 14000 products, I don't want the product_id to be repeated 3 times each, because that will make 42000 rows of data

Comment: Simply I want the rows to be broken into columns as in the example

Comment: @user3458635 Indeed, but could you not generate simpler "fake" test data for the purpose of the question. Feed that to simpler SQL (that none the less replicates the problem) and then generate the same problem with the output. The answer to this question would be more general and therefore more useful to other people as well as yourself

Comment: the thing is it is not the "fake" data. that is what it shows me after the query. I am new here and really don't know how else I can show the output. Very sorry for that

Comment: @user3458635 I see you have your answer so the question is somewhat mute but to better explain what I mean: Say I have a **huge** program that should ultimately outputs `Hèllo` but instead outputs `H#llo` then posting the entire program is unlikely to get me an answer. However; if instead I simplify the program, removing pieces, and removing pieces and seeing if the problem remains I will ultimately end up with a really small program that replicates the problem but is much easier to understand. If I post that; I will likely get my answer.

Comment: @user3458635 Did you try seeing if you still got the problem with 3 tables? What about 2? If so don't include 4 tables in your question. How about with less columns in each table?

Comment: I see your point Richard. I should have posted a smaller version of the query. Thank you so much for your time for explaining it to me

Comment: @user glad to have helped,  and glad you've got your answer

Comment: Richard, in the second question, the one i gave you the link to, there is only one table that has that problem. If i don't add this table to the rest of the 3 tables, I get the right result. The reason I posted a new question with 4 tables, is because of those guys who said that the info i provided is not full. I assumed that I had to post everything. If they had explained it to me like the way you did, probably I would have done it the right way at once.

Comment: @RichardTingle I have updated the original post with all 3 questions. Have a look.

Comment: @mehow Why are you still disturbing me? What is wrong with you?

Comment: mehow is doing a service for Stack Oveflow users, using the tools  available to him, @user3458635. Easy with the abuse.

Comment: Richard and @mehow have done some cool work helping here, for sure. Kudos to them both.

Comment: Well, on my side, i haven't seen mehow doing any good job than blocking and disturbing those people who seek for help. Today I posted the same question that was blocked yesterday within some few minutes by Mehow, without editing anything today I got lots of help from Richard and Stanislav whom I am so grateful. The reason that gave me Mehow was the question wasn't clear enough for him so he asked his friends to vote negative. Today Richard explained clearly and politely to me on how I must post my questions where mehow didn't do that.The question wasn't clear enough but i still got an answer

Comment: Mehow is a very rude person. If he didn't understand something, he could have asked me, if he didn't want to help, he could have left it for someone to answer. Because of him I wasted the whole of yesterday. Time is precious. He can't just do that

Comment: @user3458635 great, you've made my day ;)

Comment: The situation has been resolved, seemingly to the benefit of all. I think it’s time to call it a day now

Comment: Yes Richard, I agree. If I wasn't blocked yesterday and today by Mehow and his crew I wouldn't have gotten a chance to talk to you all ;). @mehow no heart feelings. A fact is always a fact. You have also made my day, if not you I wouldn't be here ;)

Comment: Thank you all once again. All of you helped me a lot!!!