# How are you wasting your time moderating Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, rant

## I need help

A particular user [asks a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629846/view-mysql-table-in-a-different-way-excel-vba).

## Just help me or shut up

After multiple attempts from the community to help the OP tidy up the question and come up with an actual question he has a go on me for not helping him and *speaking for everyone* in the comments section which a diamond mod decided to clear. His question is put on hold *(note: 5 close votes (5 peoples time) + diamond moderator time to sort out the comments section).*

## Screw that I am asking a new one

The **victim** *(as he now is thinking of himself)* doesn't bother to understand [why his question was put on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and [he asks a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657654/issue-getting-mysql-table-display-one-row-of-each-product-id-in-vba) which in fact is an exact duplicate with the exception of some more irrelevant junk dumped (*links to pictures, etc*). Again, the question receives 5 close votes and is put on hold.

## Not enough... "OMG, OMG, I am a victim of a huge crime here"

The victim [complains on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/i-dont-understand-why-i-get-blocked-by-this-users). He points out a [well organized "crime" group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/i-dont-understand-why-i-get-blocked-by-this-users/226843#comment742973_226843) *with myself being the leader... (mehow, Stijn, rene, Suhosin Pony, M42)* and does not actually tell the truth via comments. Only mentions 2 questions, possibly not realizing that deleted questions are still visible to trusted users.

## It's my way...

So the OP goes and [asks the same question already closed twice for the 3rd time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660366/mysql-break-down-the-rows-to-columns). This time he copies-paste the [1st version revised by me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22629846/revisions).

## see...

We, have [**wasted our time**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/i-dont-understand-why-i-get-blocked-by-this-users/226843#comment742969_226843) because in the end the same question 10+ people spent moderating, using their close votes, answering on Meta...etc. [remains here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660366/mysql-break-down-the-rows-to-columns).. what is the point of moderation then?

[first question deleted for <10K](http://s9.postimg.org/7qhtq7cbz/first.png)

[second question deleted for <10K](http://s8.postimg.org/4auci0wf9/second.png)

Comment: So what is the point of this post? Just downvote, vote to close and move on for users that behave that way, they'll be automatically blocked very soon.

Comment: how can you not see it? the point here is that I have done exactly what you have said to do, downvoted, voted to close and moved on. The problem is the next day I happen to come here and see the same but reposted as new question. Ok, I am doing the same thing so do 10 other people... The third day the same but another new question ( closed twice already ) is asked again and now it's answered... so what was the point of closing the first 2 questions, spending time editing it and explain to the OP why his question is not good...

Comment: Sometimes you waste time explaining the rules here to unreasonable people, there is no way to avoid that for sure. But there is also a point where a user is clearly identifiable as unreasonable, then you can easily avoid wasting time and simply don't explain, just downvote and close. And with three closed and downvoted questions the user is likely question-banned now.

Comment: At least the final question was a little better. Not an ideal situation for sure (the OP should have edited) but by all of our efforts things were at least a little better (p.s. I think you more than anyone deserve a bit of a rant about this; I have no idea why you were so heavily targeted on this one)

Comment: @RichardTingle it's because of the first question and the comments which are now  deleted. They were in the spirit of the comments under [your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/i-dont-understand-why-i-get-blocked-by-this-users/226843#226843). You're right, the question is a *little* better after a 3 days long trial but still missing the crucial part of attempts and what have you tried...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I feel your pain. Sometimes it does feel like it is a pointless exercise. Once in a while we encounter the one user who will not understand what they did wrong and will put up a fight about it. They take a lot of energy out of us. They are very noisy and very visible. It is a very negative experience.

What is less visible is all the times our interventions were successful in changing behavior. The user who gets it after one of their question is closed is not going to post another terrible question again, won't attract downvotes, and won't attract our attention. And rare are the thanks for having educated someone who did not realize that they were not using SO according to its customs or rules. There is no positive counterpart equivalent in impact to the negative experience of dealing with those users who don't get it.

I think we *are* making a difference. However, it may not *feel* that we are, because our successes are not as visible as those users who just don't get it.

(This does not mean that we cannot adjust the system to make it better at helping us making a difference.)

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly why we have question bans and why it's important that you:

- Downvote questions where appropriate, because that's what the question ban conditions are based on.
- Close inappropriate questions as soon as possible so they don't get answers.

  Although, for this particular question (the last one), if it's only a case of not showing an attempt, it shouldn't be closed according to official Stack Overflow guidelines (despite my personal opinion of what we should be doing with it).

Closing early is more important than downvoting early - keep in mind that a closed question that is edited will be sent to the reopen review queue.

I typically don't worry about downvoting too much, as I believe that if the question is edited to conform to the guidelines, there should be plenty of users upvoting it to cancel out any downvotes made by users who didn't have the commitment to stick around for long enough after downvoting to revert their vote after the edit (which really isn't something anyone should be expected to do anyway).

Moderation isn't only about leading users to the correct path, sometimes it's about taking action against users who simply don't want to conform to the guidelines - unless you're a generally evil person, this won't be something you enjoy, but it's necessary to be done for the good of the site.

Comment: Well, actually according to the [official Stack Overflow guidelines (3rd)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *`Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.`*  So can you clear my doubt and point me to the **correct guidelines** please?

Comment: The guidelines say you should show an attempt, but the close reason was removed because presumably people were closing otherwise good questions, thus it's not a valid reason to close the question by itself. The discussion starts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080), but note the links to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840). Honestly, I'm still rather confused about when things should be Unclear or Too Broad as the conditional replacements for Minimal Understanding.